# How to get index of an item in an array

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am having array called stored and I want to access their indexes so that I can select them individually to do my operations.

If I want to print their indexes, what should I do?

Answer (score 49):

use NSArray's `indexOfObject:` method. Such as the following:

```
NSUInteger fooIndex = [someArray indexOfObject: someObject];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int totalElements = [anArray count];
for(int i=0; i < totalElements; i++)
{
    data = [myArray indexOfObject:i];
}
```

The above code will give you the data if you pass in the index

```
NSString *haystackText = @"Hello World";
int totalElements = [anArray count];
for(int i=0; i < totalElements; i++)
{
    BOOL result = [haystackText caseInsensitiveCompare:[myArray objectAtIndex:i] == NSOrderedSame;
    if(result)
    {
         NSUInteger fooIndex = [myArray indexOfObject: haystackText];
         return fooIndex;
    }
}
```

The code above will first find the element in the array and if it exists then return the index.

Answer (score 2):

```
[array indexOfObject:object]
```

returns index of "object"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOfObject` method to get the index of element.

for example

This will give you index of your object

```
  NSInteger index = [yourArray indexOfObject:objectName];
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the indexes by using the count method which returns the number of elements in the array:

```
int numElements = [myArray count];
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to print out the actual index values :)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSMutableArray) has some great examples of how to iterate over an array. Then, inside the loop, you can use `NSLog` to print the index.